# Windows 8 Application Launcher with a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows

I need to set the **Windows 8 Application Launcher** to launch my WPF application as guided here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195617(v=winembedded.81).aspx

Is it possible or does it have to be a Windows 8 App (instead of a regular WPF application)?

If its not possible, how difficult would it be to migrate my WPF application to a Windows 8 App format?

Couldn't i simply package my WPF application with an AUMID?

Important: The Windows 8 Application Launcher also has a KeepAlive option in Windows Embedded. I need it to keep my application alive as well incase its closing so a good solution would include this as well. Of and i'm using ClickOnce for auto-update my WPF application and i would like to keep this functionality too.

Answer (score 0):

your example is for win 8 Embedded and only for apps. There you have the possibility to startup directly an app.

I think there is still [startup](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/where-is-startup-folder-how-to-edit-startup-items-in-windows-8/) possibility for your wpf application on normal Windows 8 devices.

Maybe you have to disable metro on startup. [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/108349/how-to-boot-to-the-desktop-skip-metro-in-windows-8/) is a complex tutorial about this. In Win 8.1 there will be a simple option inside the properties of the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the page you linked, it seems you are out of luck. Only Windows 8 apps are mentioned. But maybe there is another mechanims to auto start desktop applications?

The difficulty of migrating a classic WPF desktop application to a Windows 8 ("Store") app depends on the kind and content of the application, ranging from simple to impossible.

Windows 8 apps are sandboxed and cannot do everything a desktop application can, they have a different lifecycle and different UI/UX principles (you probably need to redo your UI from scratch). .NET and XAML for Windows Store Apps look like .NET and WPF for desktop applications, but there are many surprising details and strings attached, possibly complicating a direct port.

Answer (score 0):

Application Launcher is for Windows Store Applications only. However you can achieve the same effect with Shell Launcher for any executable.

Have a look at these two links here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn195623(v=winembedded.81).aspx
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn451259.aspx

Let me know if you need additional help.